# Trying to use Simple Injector in ASP.NET MVC site with OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, owin, simple-injector

Reading the docs [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/owinintegration.html)
..it seemed easy thing to do, but in practice things are not so simple.

One problem I had was accessing the `IAppBuilder` interface from the method that sets up the DI. I have put an `AppBuilder` public static property on Startup class for that purpose and hoped that it gets initialized first, before DI setup starts:

```
// DI setup code:
Startup.AppBuilder.Use((async (context, next) =>
{
    using (container.BeginExecutionContextScope())
    {
        await next();
    }
}));


[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(MySite.Presentation.Startup))]
namespace MySite.Presentation
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public static IAppBuilder AppBuilder { get; private set; }

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            AppBuilder = app;

            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

But it turns out that it's not.
`Startup.AppBuilder` is null when the DI gets setup.
How can I solve this?

I don't know if I can somehow get the container from within the `Startup` class but keeping the DI setup code in one place would be nice, if possible.

Comment: Where exactly is this DI setup code located? Why don't you use the value supplied to the `Configuration` method in your DI setup code.

Comment: @Steven My DI initialization is in my `Global.asax.cs`. And, apparently, it executes first, so my code above does not work. The code in your answer below would work, but I need to get the DI container somehow and 1) I don't now how (there must be a better way than using static properties) and 2) some people consider touching the DI container in places other than the DI initialization a "no-no".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.Use((async (context, next) =>
    {
        using (container.BeginExecutionContextScope())
        {
            await next();
        }
    }));

    ConfigureAuth(app);
}
```